# Using knp snappy bundle to generate pdf - symfony2

Tags: php, git, symfony, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm new to symfony2 and very to use external libraries.
I want to use the [KNP Snappy Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle), my first third party bundle.

I did exactly that is told in the git link.

```
{
    "require": {
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

// app/AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        //...
        new Knp\Bundle\SnappyBundle\KnpSnappyBundle(),
```

app/config/config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
    pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
    image:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
        options:    []
```

Then I added following line in **ACME** welcome controller to test

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generate('http://www.google.fr', '/Symfony/file.pdf');
```

It says **`The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "The system cannot find the path specified.
"
stdout: ""
command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage --format "jpg" "http://www.google.fr" "/Symfony/file.pdf".`**

I tried

```
$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml(
    $this->renderView(
        'AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index.html.twig'),
        '/Symfony/file.pdf'
    );
```

It shows **`The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "The system cannot find the path specified.
"
stdout: ""
command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy530da4525584b8.92211088.html" "/Symfony/file.pdf".`**

What I'm missing? Do I need to install anything ? Please describe how can I run it and generate a proper pdf????? I searched, I'm guessing I need to install wkhtmltoimage etc. But from where and how?

Comment: well, it looks like you're on Windows, and you specified a Linux path... I assume you didn't [download](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) the binaries.

Comment: @Touki Installed the binaries. By failing to configure the path for windows. Binaries are in C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin. So I showed the path in config.php. It  still saying `The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Show us the config file

Comment: @abbiya It's already there app/config/config.yml I also tried that Ahmed Samy Answered

Comment: What is the path of this file please app / AppKernel.php I don't have it, I imagine I have to create it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few months later, but here is what helped me.

I put the path to wkthmltopdf folder in escaped double quotes.

```
knp_snappy:
   pdf:
      binary: "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe\""
```

Answer (score 7):

you can also manage wkhtmltopdf with composer too, I did it in a recent project:

in your composer.json you can add:

```
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.11.0-RC1"
```

and in your config.yml:

```
binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these

1- Update your config.yml

```
 pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     wkhtmltopdf
    options:    []
```

- And update your windows environment PATH with `path/to/my/wkhtmltopdf`

2- Or set the path directly in config.yml

```
pdf:
        enabled:    true
        binary:     /path/to/my/wkhtmltopdf
        options:    []
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is in C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin. And using that generates this 'The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' And with 'binary:wkhtmltopdf' it says `The exit status code '1' says something went wrong:
stderr: "'wkhtmltopdf' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: I've tried to set the path variable to both bin folder and to .exe file. They are not working either.