# Symfony2: How to create a PDF from html that contains a table with dynamic content (width/height)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, pdf

I think this question has been asked and also answered before. None of them worked for me.

I have a page with table and those table has dynamically loaded data. The size of each row is dynamically calculated. So I've no control over that.

> There could be 100 letters or may be 10000 or may be none in each cell.

Till now I tried some pdf tools.I tried **FPDF** using php in controller , I also tried **JSpdf** to build pdf by rendering html view. In **FPDF** I have to declare the cell with `width` and `height`. How can I tell the width or height of a cell whom size is unknown to me.

```
$this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
```

**jsPDF** can render html a bit, but it's in beta version, can't render css. It also uses width height.

Is there any way to achieve the functionallty that a pdf will be created with HEADER in each page and each page contains a table with dynamic data whose size for each cell is totally unknown to me? The letters should be adjusted into the table cells or table cell should be adjusted according to letters.

If there is a tool that will work exactly how I wanted, then will it be possible to integrate that in Symfony2 framework? You can suggest me a tool with Jquery too,if there us any...

**Edit:**
config.php for knpsnappy (not working on windows)

```
knp_snappy:
  pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf
    options:    []
  image:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltoimage
    options:    []
```

Answer (score 0):

**KnpSnappyBundle:**

You can use **[KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle)** to create the PDF.

---

The bundle integrates **[snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy)** into symfony.

[snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) is a wrapper around **[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)** which uses the **Webkit** rendering engine.

Comment: 2 things. 1) I've tried knpsnappy. Facing a problem currently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035808/using-knp-snappy-bundle-to-generate-pdf-symfony2 Basically I've failed to configure it inside windows environment. 2) It I use it, can I load dynamic data without telling the height / width of a cell in a pdf?

Comment: Yes it creates the PDF from whatever HTML you provide as it displays in browser. You have to make the proper HTML. Show us the config file may be will figure out the problem.

Comment: @abbiya added the config file here. also asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035808/using-knp-snappy-bundle-to-generate-pdf-symfony2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
css:

```
@media print {
    .noPrint {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

js:
`window.print();` //you can call this method on event fire

But for these way you need to fixed the web page width.

or if you are in symfony then can use [dompdf bundle](https://github.com/SlikNL/DompdfBundle) or if not in symfony then can use only [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)