# KnpSnappyBundle The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have this error on knpSnappyBundle, i am trying to generate a pdf and then send it by email.

My config look like this :

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     \vendor\h4cc\bin\wkhtmltopdf-amd64\bin\wkhtmltopdf-amd64
    options:    []
```

Then my controller :

```
$html = $this->render('AppUserBundle:Emails:envoi-export.html.twig', [
                                      'pointagesList' => $pointagesList,
                                      'user'          => $user,
                                      'date'          => new \DateTime()
                                  ]);
  $filename = sprintf('test-%s.pdf', date('Y-m-d'));

  return new Response(
      $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
      200,
      [
          'Content-Type'        => 'application/pdf',
          'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename),
      ]
  );
```

Full error message :

> The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
>   stderr: "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found
>   "
>   stdout: ""
>   command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy57970542debe22.97700913.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy57970542dec563.25042325.pdf'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a working solution.

- Install wkhtmltopdf in vendor symfony2
- Install wkhtmltopdf in your virtual machine
- Install xvfb in your virtual machine
- Create a wkhtmltopdf.sh file inside your usr/local/bin where wkhtmltopdf is installed with (xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x16" wkhtmltopdf --dpi 150 --zoom 0.6 "$@")
- In your config.yml use the appropriate path like /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh

I hope it can help someone

Answer (score 3):

I Solved Problem, Its happening because system doesn't have installed `wkhtmltopdf` Plugin.
please Follow Links to install this plugin:-

- For mac OS

  https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/wkhtmltopdf

  `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
- For Linux OS

  https://computingforgeeks.com/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/

  `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Hope this helps for future endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

The "binary" chain is the static path of your computer, where you installed wkhtmltopdf. If you installed it via command lines, it should be :

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

If you installed it in your vendor repository, it should be there :

```
/path/to/Symfony/vendor/...
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to figure out same problem, I noticed at another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035808/using-knp-snappy-bundle-to-generate-pdf-symfony2) on this topic that the root directory needs to be specified in the binary location. Adding `%kernel.root_dir%` solved this error for me. Try this:

```
binary:     %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the command given in official [readme](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

```
cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/
```

with following one

```
cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```